# Web Interface For Running Cucumber and Viewing Results

Tags: continuous-integration, cucumber

I'd like to create a simple web page where anyone (ie, nontechnical users) on our team can go, click a button that says "Run All Tests", and then see a nicely formatted version of the results of a cucumber run.

Essentially, all I want is a nice web wrapper over the command-line results of typing `cucumber features` from my project root.

Are there are any open source projects that provide this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It's one of tasks of [continuous integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) systems. Despite just [running](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Continuous-Integration) your tests after hitting button, they can:

- run them after commit, installing of build, according to schedule
- email you with test results
- store results of previous runs in convenient way

I advice you to use Jenkins as a continuous integration system as it has [plugin](https://github.com/masterthought/jenkins-cucumber-jvm-reports-plugin-java) that will allow you to presents test results very nicely. Despite it's name plugin can be used with all versions of Cucumber, not just Cucumber-JVM, that can format their output as JSON.